# How to use arrow key to go different text box in gridview

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a gridview, in that I have 3 text box in each row.
If I keypress down arrow it should go to next row textbox
If I press uparrow key then it should go previous row textbox.
same for left and right arrow key.

This is my code.

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("body").keydown(function (e) {
            var row;
            debugger;
            if (e.keyCode == 39) {
                row = $(this).closest('td').next();
                row.find('input').focus();
            }
            else if (e.keyCode == 37) {
                row = $(this).closest('td').prev();
                row.find('input').focus();
            }
            else if (e.keyCode == 40) //down arrow key code
            {
                row = $(this).closest('tr').next();
                row.closest('td').next().find('.masked').focus();
            }
            else if (e.keyCode == 38) // up arrow key code
            {
                row = $(this).closest('tr').next();
                row.closest('td').prev().find('.masked').focus();
            }
        }); //this code detect is it up or down arrow
    });

</script>
```

HTML derived code

```
' <tr>
<td style="width:1%;">
<td style="width:3%;">
<td style="width:3%;">
<td style="width:3%;">
<td style="width:3%;">
<td style="width:5%;">
<input id="ContentPlaceHolderMain_grdDistanceLog_txttime_0" class="masked ui-mask" type="text" style="width:50px;display:block;" maxlength="8" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolderMain$grdDistanceLog$ctl02$txttime">
<span id="ContentPlaceHolderMain_grdDistanceLog_lbltime_0" style="display:none;"></span>
</td>
<td style="width:3%;">
<td style="width:3%;">
<td style="width:3%;">
<td style="width:3%;">
<td style="width:7%;">
<td style="width:3%;">
<td style="width:4%;">
</tr>
<tr class="alt">
<td style="width:1%;">
<td style="width:3%;">
<td style="width:3%;">
<td style="width:3%;">
<td style="width:3%;">
<td style="width:5%;">
<input id="ContentPlaceHolderMain_grdDistanceLog_txttime_1" class="masked ui-mask" type="text" style="width:50px;display:block;" maxlength="8" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolderMain$grdDistanceLog$ctl03$txttime">
<span id="ContentPlaceHolderMain_grdDistanceLog_lbltime_1" style="display:none;"></span>
</td>
<td style="width:3%;">'
```

Comment: Suggested to give all textbox an sequential id, so that you can have your jQuery codes much easier.

Comment: how it will be easier? plz explain

Comment: can you give an example

Comment: can you show your derived HTML codes? use a variable to store the current focusing ID, then +1 or -1 depends on the arrow key pressed.

Comment: tab = row.find('td').next().find('input').focus();
                    tab = tab + 1;

Comment: grdDistanceLog_txttime_0,grdDistanceLog_txttime_1 are different ids for textboxes   @Shivan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without HTML this is more guesswork than it could have been, but it seems like row.closest('td').next() is not getting the TD you're looking for.

Try:
...

```
{
    row = $(this).closest('tr').next();
    row.find('td').find('.masked').focus();
}
else if (e.keyCode == 38) // up arrow key code
{
    row = $(this).closest('tr').next();
    row.find('td').find('.masked').focus();
}
```

Edit:
With the HTML in place it seems to me like the issue at hand is $(this) not being your currently focused element, as you expect it to be, but rather the $(document), where you're firing the keydown event for. Try selecting the focused element first:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("body").keydown(function (e) {
        var row;
        var focusedElement = $(document.activeElement);
        debugger;
        if (e.keyCode == 39) {
            row = $(focusedElement).closest('td').next();
            row.find('input').focus();
        }
        else if (e.keyCode == 37) {
            row = $(focusedElement).closest('td').prev();
            row.find('input').focus();
        }
        else if (e.keyCode == 40) //down arrow key code
        {
            row = $(focusedElement).closest('tr').next();
            row.find('td').find('.masked').focus();
        }
        else if (e.keyCode == 38) // up arrow key code
        {
            row = $(focusedElement).closest('tr').next();
            row.find('td').find('.masked').focus();
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: I've added some code assuming the issue was a misinterpretation of $(this) in the context.

Comment: thanks a lot @spork, it is very close. It is taking to me the second textbox of next row in first attempt. After that it works fine. So I am marking this as answer. thanks